# Transfer C# array to PHP to show in browser

Tags: c#, php, mysql, arrays

Hy to everyone,
I have a problem that I can't solve. I've searched for the answers but I haven't find a usefull answer. I have a C# code that insert into mysql database some values, that I want to retrieve with SELECT. That array I want to display into a web browser through PHP because I need to do some things with that array.
This is my C# code I use to transfer array to PHP:

```
        while (reader.Read())
            {
                int numbers = 0;
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("numbers")))
                {
                    numbers= reader.GetInt16("numbers");
                }
                Num n = new Num(numbers);
                list.Add(n);
            }
        var Result = string.Join(",", list);

        string urlAddress = "http://localhost/Number.php";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "Result", Result}
            };
            string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(urlAddress, postData));
        }
```

And in PHP I use:

```
      <?php
      $Result = $_POST["Result"];
      echo $Result;
      ?>
```

But doesn't return anything in the web browser. I need help.

Edit: This was my PHP code. I wanted to don't use SELECT in PHP, I want from C# code.

```
    <?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "alex";
    $prefix = "";
    $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
    ?>

    Numbers:
    <form method="GET" action="Number.php">
    <?php
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enumerating");
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
            <label><?php echo $row['numere']; ?></label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['numere']; ?>" name="numar[]"><br>
     <?php }
     ?>
            <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Salveaza">
     </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['Send']))
    {
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_GET['number']);$i++)
       {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO enumerating2(numbers) VALUES('".$_GET['number'][$i]."');");
       }
   echo "<pre>Successfully!<pre>";
   }       
   ?>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with `pagesource` , where is the code you use to display it in the web browser?

Comment: I have edited my post with the last code I was in PHP.

Comment: Again, you are running the C# code, calling the PHP code and getting the result which is read by C#. You haven't shown us what C# does with that result. I think what you want to do is have PHP call the C# code and get the result not the other way around.

Comment: That Result I want to show in browser from PHP code. I wanted to transfer array in another variable in PHP. But when I open the browser show me that Undefined index: Result. Yes, I want to PHP call the C# code, but I don't know how.

Comment: First of all where is your C# code running? Web server or application? If it's application then in PHP you can run `$result = shell_exec('path\to\executable')` and in C# just write the result in a console. If it's on a web server then you can just use `file_get_contents("url of service")` . Overall this is too broad a question.

Comment: It's an application. I run $result = shell_exec('Number.exe') but the browser blocked and don't show anything.